# How can I set up an Amazon RDS for PostgreSQL database to act as a replica to a non-RDS PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql, replication, amazon-rds

I'm trying to set up an PostgreSQL database on Amazon RDS as a replica to another PostgreSQL database that lives on a regular server. Most of the instructions I've found online require shell access so that you can copy over a bunch of data files that can't be manipulated through the psql shell.

Amazon RDS for PostgreSQL does not provide shell access, so these methods won't work. Is there another way to enable streaming replication?

Thanks in advance!

PS I've seen [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/416938/using-amazon-rds-or-similar-as-a-slave) but it is not a duplicate, as it is asking about MySQL, specifically, and not PostgreSQL.

Comment: AWS blog from late 2014 describes how this can be done: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/rds-postgres-read-replicas/

Answer (score 4):

At time of writing no, you can't.

See:

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/61305/7788
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/66372/7788

Please nag them, both on the forums:

- https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=547192#547192

and via any AWS sales/support contacts you may have.

Comment: Bummer. Thanks for the links to the relevant threads. I'll be sure to reach out. :)

Comment: From that forum thread, 2014-09-10, "Amazon RDS for PostgreSQL announced support for Read Replicas, PostgreSQL 9.3.5, Data Migration enhancements."