# Postgresql read replication using an amazon postgresql RDS service as master

Tags: amazon-web-services, postgresql

we currently are using amazon Postgresql 9.3 RDS as a master database for a gaming platform. We would like to create a read only replication to use for reporting and heavy queries.

Yes, it seems like "read replica" option in amazon RDS is not active for postgresql databases.

Would it be possible to create a read replica using EC2 instance with postgresql server, taking into consideration we cannot edit pg_hba.conf among other files in the master database since its running on RDS? we can only edit postgres.conf parameters

can any one advise on what would be best way to go on with it? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replication between RDS and servers outside RDS is not currently supported by AWS.

See:

- [How can I set up an Amazon RDS for PostgreSQL database to act as a replica to a non-RDS PostgreSQL database?](https://serverfault.com/q/605460/102814)
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/61305/7788
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/66372/7788
- https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=547192#547192

Answer (score 4):

This has just changed and Read Replication is supported both internally to RDS, and via triggers to external databases.  The forum announcement is here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=2747